# Lyx Beamer presentation help

Tags: beamer, lyx

I got a beamer template from the lyx and is attached below. But the issue is like when I give the presenter mode after converting to pdf it is not as good as expected. Also I am not sure why it is showing repeated slides in left and right. Also the font size seems small. Is there any way to improve the presentation. It is for a tutorial.[the link][1]

In the link I am mentioning the template 'Abbreviated statistics tutorial by Paul Rubin
uploads:/Examples/Beamer/Rubin/stats-review.lyx (8.6 KB)'
[1]: https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Beamer